# How to resume download file using PRDownloader in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a recycler view and i want to control of downloading using buttons in my card view.
i use PRDownloader library but i have issue i can't resume download after finish the app and open it again it start the download not resume it.
my code as below

```
holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                downLoadID = PRDownloader.download(remoteLink, myLocalDirectory,
                        fileName)
                        .build()
                        .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStartOrResume() {
                                holder.pauseDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPause() {
                                holder.pauseDownloadBtn.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(string.resume_text_btn));
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.pauseDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                holder.mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.download_text));
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.pauseDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }
                        })
                        .setOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(Progress progress) {
                                video.setVideoProgress(progress.currentBytes * 100 / progress.totalBytes);

                                Log.i("videosAdapter", video.getVideoProgress() + "");
                                holder.mProgressBar.setProgress((int) video.getVideoProgress());
                                holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        })
                        .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadComplete() {
                                System.out.println("download completed");
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(string.play_video_text));
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.pauseDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Error error) {
                                holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(string.download_text));
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, error.getServerErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                holder.mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        });

            }
 if(holder.downloadResumeOrPlayBtn.getText().toString().equals(mContext.getResources().getString(string.resume_text_btn)))
    {
        PRDownloader.resume(downLoadID);
    }
        });
```

my question is how to resume the download without downloading the file from the start and if there is another library to use how can i make it.

Comment: Is the server supporting resume?

Comment: Do you mean the PRDownloaderConfig object ? Yes i add the code on my application class.

Comment: No. I mean the server. As i said.

Comment: yes, the server is supporting resume

Comment: And what is the protocol for resume? Which command is in the servers api to tell it from where to resume?

Comment: i don't know what is the protocol for resuming. i don't make an api for that. i thought that it's like when i download video using chrome so i upload videos on the server saved them on database and i query by their url.